# How to connect dataminder to other databases then provided by default sql connection?

Tags: database, plugins

How do you connect to other databases then the default provided by [dataminder](https://dataminder.pro)? 
Do you need to implement your own connection plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the default DataMinder connection uses standard JDBC url:s it can connect to any database that supports JDBC e.g. Oracle or IBM DB2.
But you need to install the correct JDBC driver as a JAVA JAR file in the plugin directory for "DM Data Plugins" located
in

```
DataMinder/Server/Internal/DMPlugins/DMPluginData/lib
```

You need to restart the application to reload the new JAR files.